# Bind attribute or ViewModel?

Tags: model-view-controller, bind, viewmodel

I'm learning about the `Bind` attribute and I have a doubt.

I can use the `Bind` attribute to include/exclude the data that will be posted, so.

Would it not be better to use a specific ViewModel instead of the `Bind` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happened if your entity changes overtime, then you might force to change all your different viewModels which you have created instead of using  Include or Exclude. it will get hard to maintain your code.

Suppose you have this :

```
  public class PersonalViewModel
    {           
            private int PersonalID { get; set; }
            public string PersonalName { get; set; }
            public string PersonalFamily { get; set; }  
            public byte? GenderID { get; set; }
            public string PersonalPhone  { get; set;}    
    }
```

Consider these :

```
public string ShowPersonalToAll(
            [Bind(Exclude = "PersonalPhone")]PersonalViewModel newPersonal)
        {...}
```

OR

```
   public class PersonalViewModel
        {           
                private int PersonalID { get; set; }
                public string PersonalName { get; set; }
                public string PersonalFamily { get; set; }  
                public byte? GenderID { get; set; }

        }
```

Now What if saving personal's mobile become important! and if you have created different customized ViewModel for several action (depends on application's business)?

Then you have to change the main ViewModel and all the other Customize ViewModel, While by using Exclude there is no need to change ViewModels, no need to change actions and the main ViewModel just changes.